# merge two arrays have a common key

Tags: php, arrays, json, merge

I have two Json arrays :

```
$arrayA = array("avg" => '1',"shape" => 'hey');

$arrayB = array("avg" => '2',"shape" => 'trapezoid');
```

I want to combine them using `javascript` or `PHP` as :

```
arrayAB = {"avg":['1', '2'], "shape":[hey', 'trapezoid']};
```

Comment: It's a really bad idea. You better have nested arrays for similar keys

Comment: What do you already have tried? Post your code, explain your difficulties, tell what is the context of the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: See this::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072348/php-merging-arrays-with-common-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arrayA = array("avg" => "234","shape" => "hey");
$arrayB = array("avg" => "5678","shape" => "trapezoid");
$array3 = array();

foreach ($arrayA as $key => $value) {
    $array3[$key] = array($arrayA[$key], $arrayB[$key]);
}
```

Comment: I tried  this and it didn't work.
<?
{
$arrayA =array("avg" => "234","shape" => "hey");
$arrayB =array("avg" => "5678","shape" => "trapezoid");
$array3 = array();

foreach ($arrayA as $key => $value) 
    $array3[$key] = [$arrayA[$key], $arrayB[$key]];
  
?>
Can you plz offer more help?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Flyingude and thanks guys for the quick replies!!
I tried This and it worked perfect the way I want it, merge two arrays, group by the keys and display the value :

<?

$arrayA = array("avg" => "234","shape" => "hey");
$arrayB = array("avg" => "5678","shape" => "trapezoid");
$arrayAB = array();

foreach ($arrayA as $key => $value) {
    $arrayAB[$key] = "[".$arrayA[$key].",".$arrayB[$key]."]";
            }
     print_r($arrayAB);
  
?>

Thanks again!!