# PHP: Combining 2 Array into 1 array with a common index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
username(
 [0] => 'andrew';
 [1] => 'teddy';
 [2] => 'bear';
)

email(
 [0] => 'andrew@andrew.com';
 [1] => 'teddy@teddy.com';
 [2] => 'bear@bear.com';
)
```

I got 2 Array coming in from post. I am processing this with PHP.
I would like to combine the array so it looks like this. 
So I can use a loop on the array to insert a query on a database.

```
[1] => Array (
 [0] => 'andrew';
 [1] => 'andrew@andrew.com';

)

[2]  => Array (
 [0] => 'teddy';
 [1] => 'teddy@teddy.com';

)

[3] => Array (
 [0] => 'bear';
 [1] => 'bear@bear.com';

)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072348/php-merging-arrays-with-common-keys this will solve all your problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

If that doesn't solve your problem, you can always just go with a simple loop:

```
foreach($usernameArray as $k=>$val)
{
    if(array_key_exists($k, $emailArray))
    {
        $combinedArray[$k] = array($val, $emailArray[$k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
$res = array ();
for($i=0;$i<count($username);$i++) {
   $res[$i][0] = $username[$i];
   $res[$i][1] = $email[$i];
}
```